# Is Hbase or BigTable like massive Matrix Store?

Tags: hadoop, hbase, bigtable

I have been doing some research on the HBase and Google's BigTable.

HBase and BigTable look like a massive Matrix store for me.

Each row key is mapped to a big m*n matrix(X), which m is the number of total rows, n is the number of total columns. And X consists total of Q k*2 matrices. Which m=Q*k, n=2*Q

Is this right?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different logical ways of looking at HBase.  You certainly can use it as a large sparse matrix.  Your description seemed slightly off to me however.

A table is a matrix; rows are composed of column families; column families are composed of column qualifiers.  Each column qualifier can have N versions.  Practically, you don't want to have more than a small number of column families in the current implementation.  So, from a matrix point of view, it is best to think of each table/row as having a single column family.

Also, your definition of X, Q, and k are not clear.  Mathematical notation is supposed to be precise, but if you use it without defining your terms, it just makes it impenetrable.